# Problem using Lloyd optimization and Mesh_domain::create_labeled_image_mesh_domain

Tags: cgal

I'm using CGAL 4.13 (Linux Fedora 29) to generate 3D meshes from segmented anathomical images. I would like to use Lloyd optimization, but I got in a reproductible way a runtime error.

In order to illustrate my problem, I modified the example **mesh_3D_image.cpp** by adding a Lloyd optimization step, as shown hereafter. The program compiles with no error/warning message.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h> 

#include <CGAL/Labeled_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Image_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Labeled_mesh_domain_3<K> Mesh_domain;

typedef CGAL::Sequential_tag Concurrency_tag;

typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain,CGAL::Default,Concurrency_tag>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3t3;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria; 

using namespace CGAL::parameters;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* fname = (argc>1)?argv[1]:"data/liver.inr.gz";
  CGAL::Image_3 image;
  if(!image.read(fname)){
    std::cerr << "Error: Cannot read file " <<  fname << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  Mesh_domain domain = Mesh_domain::create_labeled_image_mesh_domain(image);
  Mesh_criteria criteria(facet_angle=30, facet_size=6, facet_distance=4,
                     cell_radius_edge_ratio=3, cell_size=8);

  C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria);

  // !!! THE FOLLOWING LINE MAKES THE PROGRAM CRASH !!!
  CGAL::lloyd_optimize_mesh_3(c3t3, domain, time_limit=30); 

  std::ofstream medit_file("out.mesh");
  c3t3.output_to_medit(medit_file); 

  return 0;
}
```

I compile it by using the following *CMakeLists.txt* file:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_CMakeLists

project( executables )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS  )

# !!! I had to add manually the following line !!!    
find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS ImageIO)

include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )
add_executable( executables  lloyd.cpp )
add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS executables )    
target_link_libraries(executables   ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )
```

No mesh is generated. I obtain the following message:

> $ ./build/mesh_3D_image
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Precondition_exception'
>     what():  CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
>   Expr: std::distance(first,last) >= 3
>   File: /usr/include/CGAL/Mesh_3/Lloyd_move.h
>   Line: 419
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Where my code is wrong, and how can I trigger optimizations for meshes generated by 3D images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, when `CGAL::make_mesh_3()` is called like this :

```
C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria);
```

it internally launches `CGAL::perturb_mesh_3()` and `CGAL::exude_mesh_3()`. The latest changes the weights of vertices in the Regular triangulation, and should always be called last (see the Warning in the [documentation of CGAL::exude_mesh_3()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/group__PkgMesh3Functions.html#gabf09a95838226da018a742a631824af9).

The only limitation on the order is that exuder should be called last. So you can either call

```
C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria, lloyd(time_limit=30));
```

or

```
C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria, no_exude());
CGAL::lloyd_optimize_mesh_3(c3t3, domain, time_limit = 30);
CGAL::exude_mesh_3(c3t3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You removed the part:

```
  if(!image.read(fname)){
    std::cerr << "Error: Cannot read file " <<  fname << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

from the example, which is what actually reads the image from the file.

Comment: Yes, indeed I added this bug while over-simplifying the program. Now I fixed it (and I added the CMakeLists.txt file) but the problem persists: Lloyd optimization makes the program crash.